# Using a Svelte build with a Sails node server

Tags: sails.js, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to set up a website with Svelte for the frontEnd and Sails for the backend.
My problem is that I can't display my Svelte public build as my Sails default web page.
I want to keep the organization below (or maybe something similar) and have my Svelte public build page when I go on 'http://myserver:1337' instead of having the default Sails page : [file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu84D.png)

PS: I am using Node: v14.4.0, Sails: v1.2.4 and Svelte: v6.14.5.
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

1. Compile Svelt to build into the /public directory on Sails.js.

Open your rollup.config.js and change the path of your public/build/bundle.js and public/build.bundle.css to the public sails path, i.e. "../server/public...".

2. Configure /task/pipeline.js to include the compiled js and css files:

```
// tasks/pipeline.js

var cssFilesToInject = [
  'css/**/global.css',
  'css/**/bundle.css',
  'css/**/*.css',
];

var jsFilesToInject = [
  'js/**/bundle.js',
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```

3. Create a controller to load the index file:

```
// router.js

'/*': { action: 'index', skipAssets: true, skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/ },
```

The excluded "/api" routes is to allow you to configure the CRUD routes.

4. The index controller:

```
module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'View homepage',
  description: 'Display a compiled index page',
  exits: {
    success: {
      statusCode: 200,
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/index'
    },
  },
  fn: async function () {
    return {};
  }
};
```

And the index page you could include the template index.html or create your own index.ejs to load the static content, the same you configured before:

```
// views/templates/template.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <!--STYLES-->
    <!--STYLES END-->
</head>

<body>
<!--TEMPLATES-->
<!--TEMPLATES END-->
<%- body %>
<!-- exposeLocalsToBrowser ( ) %>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
</body>
</html>
```

And the index.ejs:

```
// views/pages/index.ejs

<!-- Nothing here I mean -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer it helps me to understand how does it works.
I am sorry but I did not follow your tutorial exactly (because I was not able to understand what I was supposed to do ;) ).
I edit the rollup.config.js as :

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
const BUILD_PATH = '../server/assets';

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: `${BUILD_PATH}/build/bundle.js`
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write(`${BUILD_PATH}/build/bundle.css`);
            }
        }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload(BUILD_PATH),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And I move my files is the assets as :
[file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPpn6.png)

Then I deleted the homepage.ejs in server/views/pages/

And it works :) !
Thank you again for your quick answer